# MVC Partial view nor returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to do what I believe is simple operation/request.

I have a html input text in a view and with Ajax I call the controller to return a partial view with the result of a SQL query with a where clause that comes from the text input, the goal is to retrieve a table with the info.

Below you have the code:

AJAX request from the view to call the controller:

```
$(function()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("result","result")',
        data: { Code: result},
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Partial view where I receive the model's information but when loaded in the view it does not change, there are no results:

```
@model xpto.Models.result

@if (Model != null)
{
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
           
                @Model.Code
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
}
else
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>No results</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Controller:

Only with the `HttpPost` to return the Partial View

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TableStocks(TableStocks model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
                SqlCommand selectX = new SqlCommand("sqlquery @param"), conn);
                SqlDataReader reader;
                selectX.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", model.code);
                

                connection.Open();

             


                reader = selectX.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       model.Code = Int32.Parse(reader["code"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("ERROR");
                }
            }
                

            return PartialView("result", model);
        }
```

View stays with no results even after the controller receive the value from the input text and retrieve the model with the info from the database.

```
@Html.Partial("result", Model)
```

Comment: You need to append the partial view into the DOM in your Ajax success callback function.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please give me an example?

Are you referring to something like this:

success: function (data)
                        {
                          $("#tableResult").html(data);
                        }
If yes, I still have the same result.

Note: I have on table at partial the same id="tableResult"

Thanks btw

Comment: You shouldn't ever have Html elements with the same id, ids are meant to be unique. Also, is your partial view returning just table rows?? If so, then your example above should be how you'd do it, otherwise you should be appending into the body or a div element.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I figure it out. I was not clearly when I referred to Id, however was that helped me out to understand that i need to send that to the div element.

Comment: Also, I don't see an Html table with an id of "tableResult"? If "tableResult" is the id of the table being returned in your Ajax call, you would need to have a DOM element present on initial page load to append to, so either $('body').append() or have some initial div element to append to like <div id="dynamicTableDiv"></div> then do $('#dynamicTableDiv').append(data);

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have verified that the partial view gets the model correctly.  If so, then what is left is to modify your AJAX call to replace the partial on the page as such:

```
    $(function()
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("result","result")',
            data: { Code: result},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#myDiv').html(data); //Add this line to set the data into the page
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
   });
```

Comment: Yes, when I verify the data on the browser debug tools, in the requests the answer is 200 and the preview has the table that I expect to have on the Partial View. However, it doesn't appear on the Partial View nor on the code of the page when I inspect it.

I already tried this 

 success: function (data)
                        {
                          $("#tableResult").html(data);
                        },
same result

Comment: Rui Paulino - If you do a console.log(data); what is the result?  Do you see the HTML with all the data in place?